# Solve $\int_3^4 \frac{\ln \left(x\right)+x}{e^x+x^x}\:dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

> Solve: $$\int_3^4 \frac{\ln \left(x\right)+x}{e^x+x^x}\:dx$$

I am not really sure how to attempt this. Although at first glance I thought it would be quite easy, Symbolab says that there are no steps to solve such an integral. However, WolframAlpha gives the following solution (with the corresponding graph):

[image]
[image]

Comment: Where did this integral come from?

Comment: I'm not really sure. I had it written down in my analysis notebook along with other integrals (which are not nearly as hard as this one).

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28x%2Bln+x%29%2F%28e%5Ex%2Bx%5Ex%29&dataset=) also can't find the antiderivative.

Comment: You can try numerical integration, but it seems quite lengthy and less accurate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get analytical (nasty) *approximate* solutions expanding the integrand as Taylor series around $x=\frac 72$. This would give
$$\frac{\log \left(x\right)+x}{e^x+x^x}=\sum_{n=0}^p a_n \left(x-\frac{7}{2}\right)^n+O\left(\left(x-\frac{7}{2}\right)^{p+1}\right)$$ and then
$$\int_3^4\frac{\log \left(x\right)+x}{e^x+x^x}\,dx\sim\sum_{n=0}^p \frac{ 1+(-1)^n}{2^{n+1}(n+1)}\,a_{n}$$

As a function of $p$, the numerical values are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & \text{result} \\
 0 & 0.04193840154 \\
 2 & 0.04542425123 \\
 4 & 0.04538364363 \\
 6 & 0.04538381595 \\
 8 & 0.04538378981
\end{array}
\right)$$

The only problem is that the expressions of coefficients $a_n$ are really awful.